# Problema com Update usando Hibernate no Java

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-update, orm

Salve rapaziada, eu criei uma **API REST** sem framework, utilizando o .jar Jersey.
Estou passando o Json vindo da requisição para uma classe Java, juntamente do id que esta vindo na url, porém estou com problema pra realizar o **update** do objeto.
Pesquisei em diversos sites inclusive no stackoverflow em inglês e ainda não descobri a causa do fenômeno.

Testei as funções **merge**, **update** e **saveOrUpdate**.

Testei também utilizar as funções **evict()** e **atached()** , antes das funções de update e nada mudou.

Usando a função **merge**, o hibernate faz isso:

```
Hibernate: select contato0_.id as id1_0_1_, contato0_.data_de_nascimento as data_de_2_0_1_, contato0_.grau_de_parentesco as grau_de_3_0_1_, contato0_.nome as nome4_0_1_, contato0_.sobrenome as sobrenom5_0_1_, telefones1_.contato_id as contato_3_1_3_, telefones1_.id as id1_1_3_, telefones1_.id as id1_1_0_, telefones1_.contato_id as contato_3_1_0_, telefones1_.numero as numero2_1_0_ from contato contato0_ left outer join telefone telefones1_ on contato0_.id=telefones1_.contato_id where contato0_.id=?
```

usando **update** ou **saveOrUpdate**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**O que estou utilizando:**
JDK 8, Tomcat 9, GSON, Jersey 2

---

OBS: A classe **TelefoneDAO** é similar a da foto abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Minhas Classes:**

**DAO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OperacaoTransacionalInterceptor**(corresponde a classe que será chamada ao através da anotation **@OperacaoTransacional**)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Contato**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Telefone**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não ficou muito claro qual é o problema que você quer resolver. Pode editar a pergunta? Seria tirar esse Select antes do insert?

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código como texto. Utilize markdown. Fica bem melhor pra visualizar a questão.